# Как создать свое текстовое поле в админ части OpenCart?

Tags: php, opencart

Задача.
OpenCart 2.2.x
В административной части в Каталоге есть Категории.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При редактировании Категории появляется форма-страница редактирования где можно указать названия, описание категории и т.д. Обычная `<form></form>` страница.

Нужно на странице редактирования категории добавить новое пользовательское поле типа `<input type="text" name="custom_field">`. Чтобы оно сохранялось, редактировалось и т.п.

Все это достаточно легко сделать если править ядро сайта, контроллеры, модули и т.д. Туториал: http://www.php-dev-zone.com/2015/01/how-to-add-custom-product-field-in.html

**А как сделать это в виде модуля?** Например, устанавил модуль, включил его через админку (Дополнения - Модули) и появилось пользовательское поле. Не нужно, удалил модуль. Plug&Play в общем.
Для редактирования и добавления есть идея создать отдельные таблицы. А чтобы получить данные от формы есть идея подключиться в своем модуле к событию 
`$this->event->trigger('pre.admin.category.edit', $data);`
чтобы не модифицировать ядро.

Но как вывести ПП во view в форме? Все равно придется модифицировать шаблон category.tpl?
[image: Нужно добавить свое редактируемое поле]

Answer (score 1):

Я добавлял поля так:
1) В шаблоне копировал одно из полей, Далее шел в Языковой файл , добавлял новые переменные, Записывал значения.И заменял на нужные в вьюхе.
2) Далее шел в контроллер, добавлял переменные , которые добавил в языковом файле.
3) Нужно создать поле в базе, где будут храниться данные. _ создали.
4) Идем в модель , которая обрабатывает данные, дописываем поле которые мы создали.
5) При необходимости подпиливаем контроллер еще  ( там в основном , Подтягивание данных по дефаулту, если они существуют, и отправка на обработку )

Comment: Я так понимаю, вы это сделали изменив ядро, как описано в этой статье http://www.php-dev-zone.com/2015/01/how-to-add-custom-product-field-in.html

Comment: ну админка - это не ядро. ядро находится в папке  system/....